# Why is my code returning the wrong value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

can anyone tell my why this happens?

```
checkSessionToken() {
    var sessionToken = loginCookies.get("sessionToken");

    if (typeof sessionToken !== "undefined") {
        var callback = "a";
        axios
            .get(backendServerURL + "/login.php", {
                params: {
                    action: "checkSessionToken",
                    token: sessionToken
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                callback = "b";
                console.log("---");
            });
        return callback;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

render() {
    console.log(this.checkSessionToken());
}
```

the function is always returning "a" ... but I see the "---" in the console so it should be "b" does anyone of you know why this happens .... sorry for might beeing a noob I'm new to js

EDIT: when I say

```
return "b";
```

in the

```
.then(res => {});
```

so it would be

```
.then(res => {
    return "b";
});
```

it returns undefined

Comment: callback gets set later as its async

Comment: The function you pass into `.then()` is only invoked when the `.get()` call completes. The call to `.then()` however returns *immediately*. JavaScript programming involves dealing with asynchronous APIs pretty much all the time.

Comment: sounds good but how can i return a async var?

Comment: *You cannot do that.*  You can return a Promise and use another `.then()` call to handle the `.get()` results.

Comment: can also just remove .then from inside the scope and `return axios.`, then do it outside `checkSessionToken.then()` also instead of return false you would want return Promise.reject()

Comment: thanks guys ... for everyone whos looking here ... the awnser is in the duplicate questions